# how to make two segregate searches for two different tables using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Two tables with two different search:

[image]

I have two tables Table 1 and Table 2 with two search options.

when i search in table 1  it retrieve data from table 2 .and when i search in table 2 then it also retrieve from table 1.

how we can segregate each search only for regarding specific table.

this link has only one search but i need two segregate search for two different tables in one div tag.

i have copied this code from that link.
Sorry for Poor English.Thanks In advance.

Comment: Example link: [Search Filter](https://codepen.io/adobewordpress/pen/gbewLV)

Comment: Example link: <!-- https://codepen.io/adobewordpress/pen/gbewLV -->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to make some refactor from your codepen, basically you would need to set a unique selector instead of using `.search` and `.table` for each input. I made a fork of your pen were I encapsulate a function that will receive a search selector and a table selector and will add the events to those selectors. It was a fast sketch so it can be improved a lot.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/valarauko/pen/PzrWZN)